# In Elixir, are dependent applications supervised?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

So far, I know that when I start my Elixir application, a bunch of dependent applications also get started.

Are these dependent applications started inside my app supervision tree somehow?

What happens if a dependent application crashes? Is it restarted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that Elixir works like Erlang for application.

- In Erlang each application have an independent supervision tree
- If an application crashes, this means that the topmost supervisor did crash, and that all the restart strategy failed. *There is few chance that simply adding a new layer of supervision will solve the problem.*
- it is possible to start all the dependencies using `application:ensure_all_started(Application[,StartType])`, StartType can be either

  - `temporary` : (default value): nothing occurs if a `temporary` application stops for any reason
  - `permanent` : all other applications terminate if a `permanent` application stops for any reason
  - `transient` : all other applications terminate is a `transient` application stops for any reason but `normal`
- it is also possible to call `application:ensure_started(Application[,StartType])` for each dependencies. Note that in both cases, the `StartType` only controls the effect of one application termination on the others, but there is no restart strategy applied.
- it is possible to know which applications are running using `application:which_applications()`

Comment: I believe that mix starts all applications as `:permanent` by default when the environment is `prod`. This is controlled by the `:start_permanent` project option where the default is `Mix.env == :prod`. Can anyone confirm this is the case? Also, how can per-application `StartType` be configured through mix?

Answer (score 0):

In Erlang VM all applications start as children application_master.
Every application has `StartType` which can be one of `temporary`, `transient` and  `permanent`.
A `permanent` and in some cases `transient` application crash will affect on entire Erlang VM (VM will crash and crash.dump file will created).
According to the [Elixir application module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html) you can set type of your dependencies in `start/2`.